# Find all subfolders and copy their contents

Tags: shell, find, cp, cpio

Currently I have the following code for copying all folders to a new location:

```sh
find /var/CommuniGate/Accounts/ -name 'Archive.folder' | cpio -pdm archiv_mount/
```

It works fine, but only copies the Archive.folder. How can I also copy everything that is contained in Archive.folder?

Comment: is there any reason why you don't use rsync? cpio doesn't support recursive copying of directories

Comment: `find /var/CommuniGate/Accounts -path '*/Archive.folder/*' | cpio -pdm archiv_mount/`

Answer (score 0):

With find you can execute some commands, for example copy with recursion:

```
find /var/CommuniGate/Accounts/ -name 'Archive.folder' -exec cp -Rp {} archiv_mount/ \;
```